# JScript мешает и НЕ мешает нормальной отработке странички браузера

Tags: php, javascript, kohana

Работаю с kohana.
У меня есть *view*, в котором есть "календарь" и возможность выбора картинок (с возможностью дальнейшей загрузки)

```
<?=Form::file('images[]', array('id' => 'multi'))?>
```

Для картинок, есть скрипты, которые я загружаю в контроллере

```
$this->template->scripts = array('.s/src/photo/jquery-1.6.2.min.js',
                                     '.s/src/photo/jquery.MultiFile.pack.js',
                                     '.s/src/photo/upload.js',
                                     '.s/src/photo/view_images.js',);
```

Календарик использует тоже скрипты, но они у меня прописаны в *view*

```
<script src="/.s/src/cal/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/.s/src/cal/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js"></script>
<script src="/.s/src/cal/set.js"></script>
```

**Проблема** состоит в том, что календарь работает (т.е. возможность выбрать дату), когда скрипт

```
<script src="/.s/src/cal/jquery.js"></script>
```

**НЕ** закоментирован, но при этом НЕ работает выбор изображений…
И наоборот выбор изображений РАБОТАЕТ когда вшеупомянутый скрипт ЗАКОМЕНТИРОВАН, но при этом **НЕ** работает выбор даты с помощью календаря.

Я так думаю, что где-то происходит не правильная ссылка на файлы.

Как можно от этой проблемы избавиться?

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Вы два раза загружаете jquery, один у вас прописан во view второй передаете в `template->scripts`, думаю передавать уже нет смысла если он загружен на странице. Ну и версии этих самых jquery файлов я так подозреваю разные.

Answer (score 1):

Все решил:

```
"/.s/src/cal/jquery.js"
```

и

```
".s/src/photo/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"
```

**МЕСТАМИ ПОМЕНЯЛ**
(хотя (я с jscript) мало работал, я всегда сталкивался с тем, что разные версии файлов, на их именах не отражаются)